# How to count objects in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, scripting

As I'm reading in the PowerShell user guide, one of the core PowerShell concepts is that commands accept and return *objects* instead of text. So for example, running `get-alias` returns me a number of `System.Management.Automation.AliasInfo` objects:

```
PS Z:\> get-alias

CommandType     Name                                             Definition
-----------     ----                                             ----------
Alias           %                                                ForEach-Object
Alias           ?                                                Where-Object
Alias           ac                                               Add-Content
Alias           asnp                                             Add-PSSnapIn
Alias           cat                                              Get-Content
Alias           cd                                               Set-Location
Alias           chdir                                            Set-Location
...
```

Now, **how do I get the count of these objects?**

Comment: (Get-Alias).Count

Answer (score 252, accepted):

This will get you count:

```
get-alias | measure
```

You can work with the result as with object:

```
$m = get-alias | measure
$m.Count
```

And if you would like to have aliases in some variable also, you can use Tee-Object:

```
$m = get-alias | tee -Variable aliases | measure
$m.Count
$aliases
```

Some more info on Measure-Object cmdlet is on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176900.aspx).

Do not confuse it with Measure-Command cmdlet which is for time measuring. (again on [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee176899.aspx))

Comment: I used `$Counter = $(get-alias | measure).Count` as it always returns the value 1 in case there's only one occurrence, just as you said.

Comment: Another option: `get-alias | measure | % { $_.Count }`

Comment: fyi: `measure` is short for `Measure-Object`; and returns a lot of other stuff -- like `Average`, `Sum`, `Maximum`, etc...

Comment: Why not just (gal).count? Requires PS v3 or higher IIRC. EDIT: this has already been answered.

Comment: @Shameer While we're at it, one can use [`Get-Alias | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50213477/521554) to get rid of `%` and `{}`. What is easier to write and read is for another discussion.

Comment: Also as a short version: `get-alias | measure | % count`

Comment: @Shameer, and what is the difference?

Answer (score 133):

As short as @jumbo's answer is :-) you can do it even more tersely.
This just returns the `Count` property of the array returned by the antecedent sub-expression:

```
@(Get-Alias).Count
```

A couple points to note:

1. You can put an arbitrarily complex expression in place of `Get-Alias`, for example:

   ```
   @(Get-Process | ? { $_.ProcessName -eq "svchost" }).Count
   ```
2. The initial at-sign (@) is **necessary** for a robust solution. As long as the answer is two or greater you will get an equivalent answer with or without the @, but when the answer is zero or one you will get **no** output unless you have the @ sign! (It forces the `Count` property to exist by forcing the output to be an array.)

**2012.01.30 Update**

The above is true for PowerShell V2. One of the new features of PowerShell V3 is that you do have a `Count` property even for singletons, so the at-sign becomes unimportant for this scenario.

Comment: I know this is old, but for others who go looking for this…
v3+ doesn't seem to work without the @ for count < 2 if `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest` is used. I just ran into this today (on 5.1) — something worked interactively that didn't work in a function. I tracked it down to the function have Set-StrictMode in it; when I set strict mode interactively, it didn't work, either.

Comment: Good catch, @vr8ce! I am a strong advocate of `Set-StrictMode`, too, so I should have noticed that.

Comment: To expand on @vr8ce's advice, I couldn't use @($myObject) to get a count on an existing object. So I use an `if ($myObject.PSobject.Properties.Name -contains "count")` (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997511/how-can-you-test-if-an-object-has-a-specific-property) before trying to test the count property. I hate that PoSH makes me do this but Strict Mode is worth it.

Answer (score 27):

Just use parenthesis and 'count'.   This applies to Powershell v3

```
(get-alias).count
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Damien OK. I made the edit . In SO people generally come from the first answer to the last. They wont suddenly jump into the third answer and get confused. So that I made it as a continuation of first two answers. That answer makes more sense then this edited one.

Comment: This is already covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11550227/542251). Your basically just re-iterating whats already been said two years after it's been said.

Comment: @Liam That answer is for powershell v2. My answer is for powershell v3. As you said this answer is covered/told literally in the update(2012.01.30 Update) in that answer. I just gave coding part.

Answer (score 7):

`@($output).Count` does not always produce correct results.
I used the `($output | Measure).Count` method.

I found this with VMware Get-VmQuestion cmdlet:

```
$output = Get-VmQuestion -VM vm1
@($output).Count
```

The answer it gave is one, whereas

```
$output
```

produced no output (the correct answer was 0 as produced with the `Measure` method).

This only seemed to be the case with 0 and 1. Anything above 1 was correct with limited testing.

Comment: Chris, I think to get what you wanted out that you'd need to do this:
    @(Get-VmQuestion -VM vm1).count 
You can't force the output to be an array... once the output is already made.  Which is what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

in my exchange the cmd-let you presented did not work, the answer was null, so I had to make a little correction and worked fine for me:

```
@(get-transportservice | get-messagetrackinglog -Resultsize unlimited -Start "MM/DD/AAAA HH:MM" -End "MM/DD/AAAA HH:MM" -recipients "user@domain.com" | where {$_.Event
ID -eq "DELIVER"}).count
```

Comment: You've shared good info about pulling information from Exchange using PowerShell, and hidden in there is a count, making this a valid answer but not to this question.

Comment: If you look attentively enough, you'll see that **all 4 answers** give the `@(...).Count` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Alias|ForEach-Object {$myCount++};$myCount
```

> 158

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to get total count of objects.
(Get-Alias).Count