# Merge two json objects

Tags: json, powershell, object-graph

I have the following inputs - 2 json files one is the base one and the second contains the same properties but the different values, I'd like to merge that objects.

For example:

```
{
  a:{
    b:"asda"
  }
  c: "asdasd"
}
```

And the second file:

```
{
  a:{
   b:"d"
  }
}
```

And the result should be like this:

```
{a:{b:"d"},c:"asdasd"}
```

Is that is possible with powershell?

Comment: FYI, I had to add a comma after the first JSON a: element closing bracket to make it valid JSON.

Comment: You might use the [`Merge()` method](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm) of the [`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` Namespace](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/n_newtonsoft_json_linq.htm) for this, see: [Combine / Merge two json files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75529898/1701026)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>`$Json1 | Join $Json2 -Merge {$Right.$_} | ConvertTo-Json`</strike> <sub>(see update below)</sub>

```
Install-Module -Name JoinModule
($Json1 ConvertFrom-Json) | Merge ($Json2 ConvertFrom-Json) | ConvertTo-Json
```

Result:

```
{
    "c":  "asdasd",
    "a":  {
              "b":  "d"
          }
}
```

You might consider not to overwrite the left value:

```
($Json1 ConvertFrom-Json) | Join ($Json2 ConvertFrom-Json) | ConvertTo-Json
```

In that case the result will be:

```
{
    "c":  "asdasd",
    "a":  [
              {
                  "b":  "asda"
              },
              {
                  "b":  "d"
              }
          ]
}
```

For details see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026

---

**Update 2019-11-16**
The `-Merge` parameter has been depleted and divided over the `-Discern` and `-Property` parameters (sorry for the breaking change). The good news is that the default parameter settings for an object merge are accommodated in a proxy command named `Merge-Object` (alias `Merge`) which simplifies the concerned syntax to just: `$Object1 | Merge $Object2`. For details, see [readme](https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object/blob/master/README.md) or embedded help.

---

**Note 2024-03-17**
For handeling more complex object-graphs, you might consider this [Object-Graph toolset](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ObjectGraphTools/)

Comment: didnt work for me on ps 7.0 :_(. I ended using @waxingsatirical

Answer (score 12):

Join (Join-Object) is not a built-in CmdLet

This is an extension of @Mark's answer which also recurses through child objects.

```
function merge ($target, $source) {
    $source.psobject.Properties | % {
        if ($_.TypeNameOfValue -eq 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject' -and $target."$($_.Name)" ) {
            merge $target."$($_.Name)" $_.Value
        }
        else {
            $target | Add-Member -MemberType $_.MemberType -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value -Force
        }
    }
}

merge $Json1 $Json2

$Json1
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the order of properties in target? 
When merging, I've notice that the properties are replaced towards the bottom of the object.

Comment: I actually added another condition to the else portion of the code to set a value instead of adding a member. That seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the names of the elements (per your example above), you could do it explicitly like this:

```
$Json1 ='{
  a: {
    b:"asda"
  },
  c: "asdasd"
}
' | ConvertFrom-Json

$Json2 = '{
  a:{
   b:"d"
  }
}
' | ConvertFrom-Json


$Json1.a = $Json2.a
```

Result:

```
$Json1 | ConvertTo-Json

{
    "a":  {
              "b":  "d"
          },
    "c":  "asdasd"
}
```

If you're looking for something that will merge the two without knowing the explicit key name, you could do something like the following. This will essentially overwrite any properties in the first Json with those from the second Json, where they are duplicated at the first level (it won't seek matches in the nested properties and again this is an overwrite not a merge):

```
$Json2.psobject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    $Json1 | Add-Member -MemberType $_.MemberType -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value -Force
}
```

Comment: yup I'm looking for solution that works based on matching keynames

Comment: I've amended my answer with another option to overwrite the properties of Json1 with those in Json2, but bear in mind this still isn't a true merge, but maybe gets you a little closer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @waxingsatirical 's answer with taking more care of existing properties:

```
function Merge-Object
{
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSObject]$target,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSObject]$source
  )

  $source.PSObject.Properties | % {
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/26998174
    if(Get-Member -InputObject $target -name $_.Name -Membertype Properties)
    {
      if($_.TypeNameOfValue -eq 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject')
      {
        Merge-Object $target."$($_.Name)" $_.Value
      }
      else
      {
        $target."$($_.Name)" = $_.Value
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $target | Add-Member -MemberType $_.MemberType -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value -Force
    }
  }
}
```