# How to combine two json objects in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

If i have two json files, how can I combine the objects using powershell? I would like the values in the second file to supersede the values from the first object. There is possibly nested complex objects within the json. Really I'm looking for a modern solution to `($Json1 ConvertFrom-Json) | Merge ($Json2 ConvertFrom-Json) | ConvertTo-Json` as Merge is deprecated, and i cannot use that in my azure pipeline.

```
{
"name" : "value",
"type": "someType",
"color": "green",
"someComplexObject" : value of complex object
}
```

```
{
"name" : "value1",
"color": "blue",
"someComplexObject" : value of complex object
}
```

Where the final result would be

```
{
"name" : "value1",
"type": "someType",
"color": "blue",
"someComplexObject" : value of complex object
}
```

Comment: Should `$json2.someComplexObject` just overwrite `$json1.someComplexObject`, or do you need to merge them recursively?

Comment: They'll need to also merge recursively

Comment: If the properties were all different, you could use convertfrom-json -ashashtable, then add the hashtables.

Comment: Here's a jq solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529688/how-to-merge-2-json-objects-from-2-files-using-jq/24904276#24904276

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Merge/Concatenate multiple json files using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107054/merge-concatenate-multiple-json-files-using-powershell)

TL;DR

```
@($JSON1; $JSON2) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20
```

Comment: This solution does not merge 2 objects as described by the OP. It would create an array with both objects intact.