# Combine JSON objects in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, azure-devops

I have two JSON objects and I am trying to build one object out of it. I am using an example here, but the properties/names are dynamic.

I have looked into [JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026) function, [MERGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549909/merge-two-json-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Combine-Object](http://powershelldistrict.com/how-to-combine-powershell-objects/) none of them seems to do what I want. As they either replace the values with the one or give me random results.

This is my example,

```
$aVar = '{ "oldEmployees" : [ { "firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe" }, { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" } ] }'
$bVar = '{ "newEmployees" : [ { "firstName": "Joe", "lastName": "Doe" } ] }'
```

I would like to have one JSON as,

```
{
    "oldEmployees": [
        {
            "firstName": "Jane",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        }, 
        {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        }
    ],
    "newEmployees": [
        {
            "firstName": "Joe",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        }
    ]
}
```

**BACKGROUND**: I am using a JSON object to deploy multiple resources in Azure DevOps pipeline using an ARM template. I have hit a point where I am limited to use Powershell script to combine multiple variables due to the size limit on the Azure Pipeline Variables to a max of 4K characters.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Powershell to do this

Comment: Yes, I have to add it in my Azure pipelines and my options are restricted to Powershell script.

Comment: I don't know what went wrong (maybe an older version) but the [Join-Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026) cmdlet, you refer to, gives exactly the results that you would like to have: `($aVar | ConvertFrom-Json) |` [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join) `($bVar | ConvertFrom-Json) | ConvertTo-Json -Compress` → `{"oldEmployees":[{"firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Doe"},{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}],"newEmployees":{"firstName":"Joe","lastName":"Doe"}}` (See also: [Merge two json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45549909/1701026))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you the exact JSON that you seek:

```
$combinedObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    oldEmployees = @($aVar | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty oldEmployees)
    newEmployees = @($bVar | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty newEmployees)
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

It's the same approach as Panomosh's answer, except that instead of using an array, I used a property map.  This prevents the output from having an array.

Comment: very nice @JamesQMurphy

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JamesQMurphy Okay, the only issue I have with this is, I am not getting $bVar as an array anymore. The output I have is `{ "oldEmployees":   [ { "firstName":  "Jane", "lastName":  "Doe" }, { "firstName":  "John", "lastName":  "Doe" } ], "newEmployees":   { "firstName":  "Joe", "lastName":  "Doe" } }`. Where I want it to be `{ "oldEmployees":   [ { "firstName":  "Jane", "lastName":  "Doe" }, { "firstName":  "John", "lastName":  "Doe" } ], "newEmployees":  ** [**{ "firstName":  "Joe", "lastName":  "Doe" }**]** }`. Even though there is only one employee in it.

Comment: Think it doesn't matter. But wanted to see it consistent. If not, it is okay. I believe it should work. Will keep you posted.

Comment: I have updated my answer so that `oldEmployees` and `newEmployees` are always arrays

Answer (score 4):

Simply pipe your definition to `|Convertfrom-Json`

```
$aVar = '{ "oldEmployees" : [ { "firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe" }, { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" } ] }' |ConvertFrom-Json
$bVar = '{ "newEmployees" : [ { "firstName": "Joe", "lastName": "Doe" } ] }'|ConvertFrom-Json

$aVar,$bVar|ConvertTo-Json
```

The result is ugly formatted with PSv5 it get's better with core.

```
[
    {
        "oldEmployees":  [
                             "@{firstName=Jane; lastName=Doe}",
                             "@{firstName=John; lastName=Doe}"
                         ]
    },
    {
        "newEmployees":  [
                             "@{firstName=Joe; lastName=Doe}"
                         ]
    }
]
```

Comment: This is insanely simple. I probably just thought is something more complicated. But it is simple if you know what you are doing. Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: I actually did not know you could chain variables like that `$aVar,$bVar` thanks @LotPings

Comment: Note that this still produces an array in the output JSON

Answer (score 3):

you are going to have to turn both of the JSON into powershell objects, combine them, and then turn them back into JSON. In the example above, powershell will just see them as strings.

You can do this like so:

```
$container = @()
$container += ConvertFrom-Json '{ "oldEmployees" : [ { "firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe" }, { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" } ] }'
$container += ConvertFrom-Json '{ "newEmployees" : [ { "firstName": "Joe", "lastName": "Doe" } ] }'

$combinedObject = $container | ConvertTo-Json
```

now if you view `$combinedObject` you will see:

```
[
{
    "newEmployees":  [
                         "@{firstName=Joe; lastName=Doe}"
                     ]
},
{
    "oldEmployees":  [
                         "@{firstName=Jane; lastName=Doe}",
                         "@{firstName=John; lastName=Doe}"
                     ]
}
]
```