# Problem with merging 2 JSON Files in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have to combine following 2 JSON files because the API which i use has a limit of 1000.

js1.json:

```
{
      "total":  1311,
      "limit":  1000,
      "offset":  0,
      "data":  [
          // 1000 Users
         ]
}
```

js2.json:

```
{
      "total":  1311,
      "limit":  1000,
      "offset":  1000,
      "data":  [
          // 311 Users
         ]
}
```

What i need:

```
{
      "data":  [
          // All 1311 Users
         ]
}
```

I have seen a few posts where it is written you could just add the JSON files together. But in the end I always get this:

[image]

Current PS Code:

```
 $js1 = Invoke-RestMethod 'API Request with offset 0' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers -Body $body | ConvertTo-Json
 $js2 = Invoke-RestMethod 'API Reuqest with offset 1000' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers -Body $body | ConvertTo-Json

 $js1 + $js2 | Out-File -FilePath .\cloudUsers.json
```

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549909/merge-two-json-objects

Comment: If you look at the second part of the accepted answer, that is what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549909/merge-two-json-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do if you only want the content of the data field then you can extract it to a PSObject and merge them and convert it back to JSON if that is the format you want.

```
$json1 = (Get-Content .\js1.json | ConvertFrom-Json)
$json2 = (Get-Content .\js2.json | ConvertFrom-Json)


$data = $json1.data + $Json2.data

$data | ConvertTo-Json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to combine the `data` values and create a new JSON with a `data` property, you can do the following:

```
$js1 = Get-Content js1.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$js2 = Get-Content js2.json | ConvertFrom-Json

[pscustomobject]@{data = $js1.data + $js2.data} | ConvertTo-Json
```

---

If you want to maintain the original JSON schema, you can update the properties accordingly:

```
$js1 = Get-Content js1.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$js2 = Get-Content js2.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$js1.limit = $js1.total
$js1.data += $js2.data
$js1 | ConvertTo-Json
```