# Powershell replace values in target.json with values from source.json

Tags: json, powershell, psobject, pscustomobject

I have a big target json file (parameters_general.json) where all common settings for a deployment are set.
For each tier I have another json file (ex: parameters_dev.json, parameters_test.json, ....) Settings set in one needs tobe added to the general.json, or overwrite it when already in general.

ex: parameters_general.json

```
{ 
  "general": {
    "db_Policy": {
    "type": "Periodic",
    "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
    "periodicModeProperties": {
      "backupIntervalInMinutes": 240,
      "backupRetentionIntervalInHours": 8,
      "backupStorageRedundancy": "Local"
    }      
  },
  "databases": [
    { 
      "name": "CtrlWps", 
      "Containers": [
        {
          "name": "ControllerAuthentication",
          "partitionKey": "id"
        }
      ],
      "ContainersTTL": []
    },
    { 
      "name": "CpoOcpi",
      "Containers": [
        {
          "name": "Cpos",
          "partitionKey": "cpoId"
        },          
        {
          "name": "OcpiCdrLastRecoveries",
          "partitionKey": "id"
        },
        {
          "name": "Routes",
          "partitionKey": "ocpiCpoId"
        }
      ],
      "ContainersTTL": [
        {
          "name": "OcpiCdrs",
          "partitionKey": "pk",
          "ttl": 172800
        },
        
        {
          "name": "OcppTransactionIds",
          "partitionKey": "pk",
          "ttl": 172800
        },
        {
          "name": "Sessions",
          "partitionKey": "pk",
          "ttl": 172800
        }     
      ]
    }
  ],
  "system_engineers": [
  ],
 }
}
```

If I want to updatethis with.

ex: parameters_test.json

```
{ 
  "general": {
    "system_engineers": [
      {
        "name": "hans",
        "AppPrincipalId": "<id>",
        "permissions": [
          "get",
          "list"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "John do",
        "AppPrincipalId": "<pid>",
        "permissions": [
          "all"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This works, the users are added to the empty "sytem_engineers" node in the parameters_general.json.

However, If I just want to change a setting on a lower node example:

ex: parameters_dev.json

```
{
  "general": {
    "databases": [
        { 
          "name": "CtrlWps", 
          "Containers": [
            {
              "name": "ControllerAuthentication",
              "partitionKey": "pk"
            }
          ]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

for replacing the partitionKey in one of the databases it replaces the whole "databases" part so I lose all other database configurations in the target.

The code I use is the following.

```
function ExtendJSON($base, $ext)
{
    $propNames = $($ext | Get-Member -MemberType *Property).Name
    foreach ($propName in $propNames) {
        if ($base.PSObject.Properties.Match($propName).Count) {
            if ($base.$propName.GetType().Name -eq "PSCustomObject")
            {
                $base.$propName = ExtendJSON $base.$propName $ext.$propName
            }
            else
            {
                $base.$propName = $ext.$propName
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $base | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $propName -Value $ext.$propName
        }
    }
    return $base
}

$tier = 'dev'  
$parametersJsonGeneral = Get-Content -Path "./parameters/parameters_general.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
#Write-Output "#####################"
$parametersJsonTier = Get-Content -Path "./parameters/parameters_$($tier).json" | ConvertFrom-Json   # overwrites existing values in $parametersJsonGeneral
ExtendJSON $parametersJsonGeneral $parametersJsonTier
```

Is there a way to loop over the settings from the lowest level up to the higher, and replace only these?

The proposed answer  does only work one 1st level THIS WORKS

```
function merger ($target, $source) {
    $source.psobject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.TypeNameOfValue -eq 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject' -and $target."$($_.Name)" ) {
            merger $target."$($_.Name)" $_.Value
        }
        else {
            $target | Add-Member -MemberType $_.MemberType -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value -Force
        }
    }
}


$Json1 ='{
    "a": {
      "b":"asda"
    },
    "c": "asdasd"
  }
  ' | ConvertFrom-Json
  
  $Json2 = '{
    "a": {
      "b":"d"
    }
  }
  ' | ConvertFrom-Json

merger $Json1 $Json2
```

However with this I loose data in $Json1

```
$Json1 ='{
    "a": {
      "b": [
          { 
            "name": "admin",
            "appconfig": {
                "test1": true,
                "test2": false
            }
          }
        ]
    },
    "c": "asdasd"
  }
  ' | ConvertFrom-Json
  
  $Json2 = '{
    "a": {
        "b": [
            { 
              "name": "admin",
              "appconfig": {
                  "test1": false
              }
            }
          ]
    }
  }
  ' | ConvertFrom-Json

merger $Json1 $Json2

{
  "a": {
    "b": [
      {
        "name": "admin",
        "appconfig": {
          "test1": false
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "c": "asdasd"
}
```

test2 is gone!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to post general comments yet, so I'll have to post it as an answer:

I tested the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51283823/18815893) to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45549909/18815893), and it did what you asked.  The advantage of this answer is that it doesn't depend on importing a separate module.

There's another answer in the same question that provides link to a more general module that provides for different types of merges (Left Join, Inner Join, etc.) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45563467/18815893), which links to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026).  However, one commenter said that it didn't work with powershell 7.0.

Comment: I tried this one, and it does not what I need.
It replaces the whole databases node.

Comment: Also the Join-Object, merge does not work like this.

Comment: I added a new example based on the anwer you gave me.