# Combine one JSON to another json objects in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I have two json files, and I want to combine one json file as object to another json file.

My first `C1` json like:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "connections_TestValue_name": {
            "defaultValue": "TestValue",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": []
}
```

And another `C2` json like:

```
{
    "kind":  "V2",
    "properties":  {
                       "displayName":  "XXXX.XXX",
                       "authenticatedUser":  {
                                                 "name":  "XXX.XXX"
                                             },
                       "overallStatus":  "Connected",
                       "statuses":  [
                                        {
                                            "status":  "Connected"
                                        }
                                    ],
                       "connectionState":  "Enabled",
                       "parameterValues":  {

                                           },
                       "customParameterValues":  {

     ...
     ...
}
```

Now, **I need to insert Json file `C2` as object `"resources": []` to another json file `C1`**, like:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "connections_TestValue_name": {
            "defaultValue": "TestValue",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
      {
       "kind":  "V2",
       "properties":  {
        ...
        ...
      }
  ]
}
```

**Note:** `C1`, `C2` are not actual files, they are obtained by other scripts.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself. Note this is *not* a script factory (maybe you should try  [Chat-GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChatGPT) instead). You will need to write the) script yourself. If you run into a problem that isn't yet covered by the existing questions and answers, you might post your [mcve] here so that we might be able to help you further. See also: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: See: [Combine / Merge two json files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75526443/1701026)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not an expert in powershell, I found the answer after many tries and debugging:

```
$C1= $C1 | ConvertFrom-Json
$C2= $C2 | ConvertFrom-Json

$C1.resources+= $C2

$C1New= $C1 | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100

Write-Host "$C1New"
```

Answer (score 1):

Direction:

```
$C1Data = ConvertFrom-Json $C1 -AsHashTable
$C2Data = ConvertFrom-Json $C2 -AsHashTable
$C1Data.resources = $C2Data
$C1Data |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
```

Comment: When I using your could to test, it gives the error "ConvertFrom : The term 'ConvertFrom' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.", `c1`, `c2` are the values I get through the API, do I need to pay attention to its path? when i use ConvertFrom?

Comment: Thanks for your input. But stillnot work for me, it return the error "ConvertFrom-Json : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AsHashTable'", I have tried all these methods, but it seems that something has been wrong, which is why I opened this post

Comment: Apparently you are still on Windows PowerShell, to use the [`-AsHashTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json#parameters) parameter, you will need at least PowerShell 6. In other words, I recommend you to [install the latest version of PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows) or use the [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member) cmdlet to add the `.resources` property to the `PSCustomObject`