# How to use adb shell command to check path exist in Android Emulator with PowerShell

Tags: android, powershell

I am new to Powershell, and I want to check if specfic path exits in Android emulator, I need to use it in PowerShell. I try to print the result of `adb shell ls /data/local/tmp/`, it will list files, and if the path does not exist, it will show No such file, but how to detect it? Any one knows?

Comment: http://codewiki.wikidot.com/shell-script:if-else

Comment: I need to run in powershell, yours answer is for shell

Comment: you have powershell installed on your android device?

Comment: No, I use adb shell command

Comment: so you use unix shell, read the link i posted above

Comment: I think the link does not contain the answer to my question, thank you anyway

Comment: So: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526285/how-to-count-objects-in-powershell ? It may help to edit your question with what you've written already.

Comment: so what do you want to achieve actually? to test on your android device if the given directory exist? if so, what then?

Comment: Thank you Morrison, I try your approach, it works in most cases, because the count I get when file does exits is 2, but when the path exists and it contain 1 file the count is also 2. So  I think I need to some deeper detect.

Comment: Hi pskink, yes I want to detect whether the path exist in android device, but it is needed to detect it in an Powershell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I have found my way to check it

```
 $checkPathExists = (adb shell ls $pathToCheck) | Out-String
if($checkPathExists -match 'No such file or directory')
{
    Write-Host "$pathToCheck path does not exist. Try to create it ..." -ForegroundColor Red
    adb shell mkdir $pathToCheck
    if(!$?)
    {
        Write-Host "Creating $pathToCheck folder failed!" -ForegroundColor Red
        exit 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Validaitng paths are done using the Test-Path cmdlet on Windows/OSX/Linux.

Get parameter, examples, full and Online help for a cmdlet or function

```
(Get-Command -Name Test-Path).Parameters
Get-help -Name Test-Path -Examples
Get-help -Name Test-Path -Full
Get-help -Name Test-Path -Online
```

Then just use If/Then, Try/Catch to perform actions based on your needs.