# Powershell get Get-Measure property value

Tags: powershell

How do I get to the Get-Measure Count property value through piping without surrounding with parenthesises? (Powershell version 5)

I would like something like `alias | measure | $_.Count`.

---

#### TL;DR

Say I want to count the number of aliases in Powershell so I go

```
alias | measure | Select-Object -Property Count
```

Which returns a `PSCustomObject` and not the `Int32` I was looking for.

Instead I can

```
alias | measure | foreach { $_.Count }
```

which relies on `Get-Measure` returning one and only one object. It works for this simple case but is IMO even then ugly.

Another working solution is to

```
( alias | measure ).Count
```

but I really don't like having to surround with parenthesises, especially when the `alias|..|..|..|measure` code gets long.

Finally I could

```
alias | measure | % { $_.Count }
```

which seems to be the best. But the `{...}` annoys me.
This latter version is the best so far.

Comment: Why not using this: `Get-Alias | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count`

Comment: `Select-Object` normally returns a custom object with the selected properties. To get just the value of a property you need to expand that property (see above).

Comment: @Olaf Please write your comment as an answer. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "extract" a single property from a custom object you can use `-ExpandProperty` like this:

```
Get-Alias | 
    Measure-Object | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
```

Comment: Don't understand the downvote on this answer. Upvoted.